# How to compare models with the same parameters but different numbers of points

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection

I am trying to determine whether an exogenously specified (human-spotted) structural change in a time series is significant, and my method is as such:

a) calculate likelihood for an ARIMA(2,1,2) for the series of points prior to the change point
b) calculate likelihood for an ARIMA(2,1,2) for the series of points after the change point
c) calculate ARIMA(2,1,2) likelihood for the entire time series

Problem: likelihood of the full series is higher, which is not surprising because likelihoods rise as n rises.

Can you recommend a way to compare models with the same parameters but different numbers of points?

One idea I have considered is using "mean absolute scaled error," as explained here: https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/compare.htm

Another is simply "normalizing" the likelihood by each likelihood by the appropriate n.

Or would you say that my method is irretrievably problematic and/or unjustified?

Answer (score 0):

The method itself is problematic, by introducing a human-spotted structural change increases the complexity of the model, and this complexity is not comparable. Imagine in a extreme situation when every points are spotted changepoints, the ARIMA(2,1,1) for each point is obviously over parameterized, lead to a likelihood of value 1 of every part.

Also, both of the two parts' model in your example are ARIMA(2,1,2),  the structure doesn't change at all.

We have a tendency to "discover" patterns from random observations, don't mislead by our nature. If you think ARIMA(2,1,2) is not enough to capture all the variations, you can increase model complexity by increasing lag orders, like ARIMA(3,1,3), or using a totally different model like HMM to explicitly catch changepoints itself.

Comment: I should've been clearer: I'm trying to determine whether a proposed change point is truly a change point.  I'm NOT looking for any other change points.  Can anyone respond to the idea of comparing the likelihood of an ARIMA with n points to an ARIMA with 2n points?